# Protect Android library by obfuscation, excluding source code or other measure?

Tags: android, obfuscation, android-library

I have created an Android library and I would like to protect the library code from reverse engineering. To my understanding, I could either use obfuscation (i.e use proguard) or create an Android Library without the source code. Also I have read some posts that recommend to use both approaches. What is the best approach to use and potential limitations? Is there any other solution you recommend?

Thanks, 
Lupe

Answer (score 0):

You should use both, but I guess it won't be enough. Managed languages are very easy to decompile. Android code seems to be even easier to reverse enginner, because of use of built-in libraries. You cannot obfuscate system libraries, so with calls to system libraries your code becomes more and more obvious.

For me you have two ways of dealing with the problem:

- rewrite your library in C. Compiled languages are much safer.
- rely on the law. Nobody can use your library or its parts when it's officially protected by law as your intellectual property.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, relying on the law is somehow the last solution to the problem. Currently I'm more interested about what android developers are usually implementing to protect the source code of their android libraries.